# sqlx named query inserting new ST_MakePoint - column not found

Tags: postgresql, go, postgis, sqlx

I had a table in Postgres which holds lat/lng and `geography(POINT,4326)`. I'm using sqlx and `db.PrepareNamed` statement to insert a new value into the table like this:

```
create, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO loc(longitude, latitude, geog) VALUES (:longitude, :latitude, ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude) )`)
```

When I run it I receive ***an error: `column longitude not found`***

And it is working fine when `ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude)` replaced with `ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0)`

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE loc(
    id  BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    longitude    float8   NOT NULL,
    latitude    float8   NOT NULL,
    geog geography(POINT,4326) NOT NULL
);
```

***Is it possible to incorporate insert `ST_MakePoint` into DB with `PrepareNamed` statement?***

---

Does not work:

```
    create, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO logs.logs(key, user_id, scope, data, longitude, latitude, geog) VALUES (:key, :user_id, :scope, :data, :longitude, :latitude, ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude) )`)

create, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO logs.logs(key, user_id, scope, data, longitude, latitude, geog) VALUES (:key, :user_id, :scope, :data, :longitude, :latitude, ST_MakePoint(:longitude, :latitude) )`)
```

---

Works:

```
create, err := db.PrepareNamed(`INSERT INTO logs.logs(key, user_id, scope, data, longitude, latitude, geog) VALUES (:key, :user_id, :scope, :data, :longitude, :latitude, ST_MakePoint(0.0, 0.0) )`)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this as well and received the same error. `longitude` - should be using the column name, while `:longitude` should be using an injected value from DTO, if I understand correctly.